# How to sort a list in ascending or descending order?

Tags: list, sorting, erlang

Is there a way to sort all the elements of a list in ascending or descending order?

```erlang
> List1 = [4,3,2,6,1,5].
> sort(List1) == [1,2,3,4,5,6]
> true
```

Comment: `lists:sort(List1)`? The documentation for that function is the first result if you search "erlang sort list".

Comment: whoops, thanks. The documention for erlang is bad for beginners

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich The docs site is slightly awkward until you learn how the OTP project itself is structured. I remember being intensely frustrated early on. Now that I know my way around navigating them is a snap, and any module I don't recall how to get to I do a search for on any search engine and get exactly that page straight away. *But there is a happy ending to this story.* Erlang's core docs are *remarkably* thorough and really all you need to know how to really flex the language (not the case with most languages). A small price to pay for such power. Skim the stlib & 'erlang' docs once.

Comment: @zwq9 Thanks! My erlang skills are improving radically, after I got the hang of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lists:sort([2,3,6,5,1,7,13,4]).
```

or

```
lists:sort(ListToSort).
```

will return a sorted list of integers in an ascending order. Thanks to @Dogbert for pointing out the obvious.

Answer (score 3):

We have a lot of way to sort, so sometime you can do that for yourself. It's the way I learnt Erlang :)

```
-spec sort(List) -> SortedList when
  List :: [integer()],
  SortedList :: [integer()].
sort([Pivot | Tail]) ->
{Smaller, Larger} = partition(Pivot, Tail, [], []),
sort(Smaller) ++ [Pivot] ++ sort(Larger);
sort([]) -> [].

partition(Check, [Head | Tail], Smaller, Larger) ->
    case Head =< Check of
        true -> partition(Check, Tail, [Head | Smaller], Larger);
        false -> partition(Check, Tail, Smaller, [Head | Larger])
    end;
partition(_, [], Smaller, Larger) -> {Smaller, Larger}.
```